# Why is there no Earth 1 Jesse Wells

Tags: character, arrowverse, the-flash

In season 2 of The Flash, you meet Earth 2 Harrison Wells and his daughter Jessie. However, she has no E1 doppelganger.

Comment: Is there anything in the show to indicate that everyone has a doppelganger on every alternate Earth? Because I'd find that very hard to believe.

Comment: Actually, there is no Harrison Wells in Earth 1, then how Jessie?

Answer (score 4):

Most probably because Eobard Thawne killed Harrison Wells too early and took over the identity that Harrison Wells got no chance to bear a child. Also, there is no Harrison Wells in earth 38 mentioned yet or Supergirl in earth 1 etc etc. So it seems every earth don't have the same person's doppelganger.

Answer (score 0):

There probably isn't a Supergirl on earth 1 because Supergirl is originally from Krypton, so her doppelganger would be on Krypton in the Earth 1 universe, the same with Superman. Since doppelgangers tend to be different than each other they may have never come to earth 1 at all. I do agree with the idea that not everybody would have a doppelganger though, because if a person died before having children, like Earth 1 Wells, it would wipe out all of their possible descendants and this would be very unlikely to happen in every universe in the multiverse, leaving lots of people without doppelgangers.